# Finding matching blocks of code and add or replace content in the second last line

Tags: awk

I posted recently a similar question but got a few more requirements now.

I've got terraform files and I need to find one or multiple specific resources blocks within it and modify those or add a `tags` block if it's missing at all.

Sample Input - An example how a file with blocks might look (but could have more lines of data in each section):

```
resource "aws_instance" "ec2_1" {
    ami = "ami-blahblah"

    tags {
        Owner = "Me"
    }
}

resource "aws_instance" "ec2_2" {
    ami = "ami-blahblah"
}

resource "aws_security_group" "gid-lb_1" {
    description = "Security group for the load balancer"

    ingress {
        security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.gid-lb_1.id}"]
    }

    tags = merge(
    var.tags,
    map(
        Type = "ec2"
        By = "Terraform"
        Owner = "Me"
        )
    )
}

resource "aws_route" "non-default-route" {
  route_table_id            = "exampleid"
}
```

Expected Output - Given the above I'd expect the following output:

```
resource "aws_instance" "ec2_1" {
    ami = "ami-blahblah"

    tags = merge(
    var.tags,
    map(
        Owner = "Me"
        Type = "ec2"
        By = "Terraform"
        )
    )
}

resource "aws_instance" "ec2_2" {
    ami = "ami-blahblah"

    tags = merge(
    var.tags,
    map(
        Type = "ec2"
        By = "Terraform"
        )
    )
}

resource "aws_security_group" "gid-lb_1" {
    description = "Security group for the load balancer"

    ingress {
        security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.gid-lb_1.id}"]
    }

    tags = merge(
    var.tags,
    map(
        Type = "ec2"
        By = "Terraform"
        Owner = "Me"
        )
    )
}

resource "aws_route" "non-default-route" {
  route_table_id            = "exampleid"
}
```

I need to search for a list of different resource blocks like `aws_instance` and `aws_security_group` which starts with `resource` and check if there is a `tag` already set and if it's set, if it contains the `map` without the curly brackets or not. All other resources and so on should be not touched.

As you can maybe see, there are resources which are not support to be modified. Also, there might be other blocks like `modules` (didn't add this example since the code block is already quite huge).

I wrote a bash script, searching for the specific resource blocks using this awk:

`awk '/^resource "/ {i++}; i=='$i' && k=='$k' {print}; /^}/ {k++}' file`

and using the list of tags to add with an array:

```
ARRAY=( "Type:ec2"
        "By:Terraform")
```

anyway, the problem here was, that I didn't find a way to replace just this one block within the text file and how to actually add the `tags` at the end before the last closing `}`.

I got help in my previous question, with an awesome awk [code](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/631978/430768). Which did the job perfectly fine, besides the problem that I can't filter it for the specific resource types.

I am really frustrated with the documentation about awk I found. I am struggling with this issue now for a bit and spend many hours and by far the biggest help was the last mentioned awk code. I would be very thankful if someone could help me out here - maybe I was searching for the wrong keywords to actually find the right documentation to help myself adding my latest use-case to the given awk code.

Many thanks!

PS: I hope it's right to open a new question on that specific case since it's slightly different now. I hope it's ok I post the link with the former [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/631978/430768).

Comment: Hi @Cyrus, thanks for the comment. I removed few lines now. Hard to find the right balance to be honest. Hope it's a little better now.

Comment: In your output file, you have an aws_instance resource named ec2 named twice. This will cause an error in AWS?

Comment: Hi @RamanSailopal, I corrected it but this code is just a simple example for the in- and wanted output. AWS itself isn't accessing those resource names but Terraform wouldn't be happy. However, I tried to remove as much as possible even within the resources block, so that code like that would fail now anyway. The full code block took too much space.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following GNU awk solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS="resource" } $0 ~ /(aws_instance)|(aws_security_group)/ && $0 !~ /map/ && $0 ~ /tags/ { tags=gensub(/(^.*)(tags {.*\n[[:space:]]+)(.*)(\n[[:space:]]+})(.*$)/,"resource\\1tags=merge(\n    var.tags,\n    map(\n        \\3\n        Type = \"ec2\"\n        By = \"Terraform\"\n        )\n    )\n    \\4",$0);print tags;next } $0 ~ /(aws_instance)|(aws_security_group)/ && $0 !~ /map/ && $0 !~ /tags/ { print "resource"$0"\n    tags=merge(\n    var.tags,\n    map(\n        Type = \"ec2\"\n        By = \"Terraform\"\n        )\n    )\n\n}";next } { print "resource"$0 }' file
```

Explanation:

```
awk 'BEGIN { 
             RS="resource"                                                           # Set the record separator to "resource"
           } 
     $0 ~ /(aws_instance)|(aws_security_group)/ && $0 !~ /map/ && $0 ~ /tags/ {      # Process when resource type is aws_instance or aws_security_group, record doesn't contain map and record contains tags
             tags=gensub(/(^.*)(tags {.*\n[[:space:]]+)(.*)(\n[[:space:]]+})(.*$)/,"resource\\1tags=merge(\n    var.tags,\n    map(\n        \\3\n        Type = \"ec2\"\n        By = \"Terraform\"\n        )\n    )\n    \\4",$0);                     # Split the line into section, substituting the line for the third section surrounded by the amended tag text. (We are incorporating the existing Owner="Me" text into the new tag text) Read this new text into the variable tags
             print tags;                                                             # Print tags                                         
             next                                                                    # Skip to the next record
            } 
      $0 ~ /(aws_instance)|(aws_security_group)/ && $0 !~ /map/ && $0 !~ /tags/ {    # Process when there are the required resource, no map and no tags
             print "resource"$0"\n    tags=merge(\n    var.tags,\n    map(\n        Type = \"ec2\"\n        By = \"Terraform\"\n        )\n    )\n\n}";                      # Print the amended tags text
             next                                                                    # Skip to the next record
            } 
            { 
             print "resource"$0                                                      # In all other cases, print the record separator "resource" plus the record ($0)
            }' file
```

Comment: hi! thank you very much! just wanted to give you a quick feedback. I tried it with two different gawk (macOS and centos) and I'm hitting in both cases a `awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=test.tf FNR=6) warning: gensub: third argument ` "aws_instance" ` error. I'm still trying to figure out what it is about but will give you a feedback asap :) appreciate it!